# only messages from my facebook profile to the bot triggers the call to my webhook

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/facebook-messenger-bot-python.html) twilio tutorial on how to set up facebook messenger. However this bot only triggers my webhook when I send a message to it on my facebook profile. The webhook I set up isn't called at all when any other facebook user sends a message to my bot.
I've tried getting the other user to follow and like the bot's page and also getting the bot to reply back. It seems only messages from my facebook profile to the bot triggers the call to my webhook. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by submitting your app for **review**.

Before you do that, it will only work for user accounts that have a role in the app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/submission-process and   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review
provide more detailed information on the whole process.

Comment: How strict is the review process? What If I get approved for a trivial use case and then change the backend to do something completely different, how will facebook know?

Comment: How will Facebook know what your _backend_ does to begin with? :-) But in general, I would not recommend “cheating” here. If they find out, they might block/delete your app, or remove your developer access altogether.